# Auto_ptr to external C struct

Tags: c++, memory, destructor, auto-ptr

I would like to create an `Auto_Ptr` to a legacy C `struct;` I only have header files and static libraries so I cannot modify the source code. I wondered wouldn't the `auto_ptr` automatically try to call the `Destructor ~foo()` if I call `p.release()` or `p.reset()`? This destructor does not exist for the C `struct`. My current solution is to write a C++ wrapper class that presents
a destructor interface (internally it uses the library-specific C methods to release memory and destroy other resources). Is there a nicer way to do it; or has this problem already been solved by `Boost` etc.?

Comment: Remember that in C++ the only difference between `struct` and `class` is that `members are by default `public` in a `struct` but `private` in a `class`. This means that you can have member functions in a `struct` like in a `class`, including constructors/destructors. And that the C++ compiler will add default constructors/destructors if you don't have any.

Comment: I was aware of that-- in my case C++ cannot possibly do the correct thing in the auto-generated destructor. I could edit the header-file and add functions but this wouldn't be a clean solution since for each new revision of the system header I would have to do that modification again. Does using a C++ wrapper sound like a good solution though?

Answer (score 2):

There still exists an implicit destructor when compiled with c++, so its fine. If the struct is allocated with `new`, that is.

Comment: Also note, that auto_ptr is depricated, consider using unique_ptr instead.

Comment: How can you give `auto_ptr` a custom deleter??

Comment: @Kerrek SB my bad, you can not. As you can see it is too infexible and has thus been depricated. Edited answer accoringly.

Comment: I cannot use C++11 due to portability reasons; the library needs to be compiled with GCC 4.3.2

Comment: @MatthiasHueser there is boost::unique_ptr that works in c++03